# ¿Cómo se puede añadir el signo % a un resultado que es un valor numérico?

Tags: python, funciones

Me gustaría plantear una duda que tengo respecto un programa, puesto que soy nuevo en Python y estoy practicando con condicionales. Mi programa es este:

```
print("QUE PORCENTAJE DE UNA HORA HA TRANSCURRIDO?")

minuto=int(input("Introduzca el minuto: "))

def porcentajes_hora(hora):

 porcentaje=minuto/.6

 if minuto>60:
  porcentaje=("MINUTO INCORRECTO")

 return porcentaje

print(porcentajes_hora(int(minuto)))
```

Como pueden ver, lo que hace es preguntar el minuto de la hora que queremos averiguar su porcentaje en tipo de dato "int". Por lo que si le ponemos "30", el programa responde con "50.0". Lo que me gustaria saber es cómo puedo modificar el código de modo que después del "50.0" se ponga el signo de porcentaje, de manera que la respuesta final sea "50.0%".

Gracias de antemano por su atención, me sería de gran ayuda si me pudieran resolver esta duda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) retornando una cadena como haces en caso de que el minuto sea mayor a 60.

```
porcentaje = "{}%".format(minuto / 0.6)
```

ó:

```
porcentaje = "{:%}".format(minuto / 60)
```

---

El método `format` sustituye las dianas definidas por `{}` por los argumentos pasados como argumentos.

Puedes usar el "[Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)" para, por ejemplo, definir el número máximo de decimales que quieres mostrar.

Algunas observaciones:

- No estas usando el argumento hora de la función, sino la variable global minuto. Deberías usar la variable que le pasas como argumento.
- Considera usar cuatro espacios entre niveles de identación, como se recomienda en PEP-8.
- Si el valor de minuto es mayor de 60 deberías evitar calcular el porcentaje. Usa un `else`  o haz que la función retorne.

El código podría ser algo así:

```
def porcentajes_hora(minuto):
    if minuto > 60:
        return "MINUTO INCORRECTO"
    return "Ha pasado un {0:.2f}% de la hora".format(minuto / 0.6) 

print("¿QUÉ PORCENTAJE DE UNA HORA HA TRANSCURRIDO?")
minuto = int(input("Introduzca el minuto: "))
print(porcentajes_hora(minuto))
```

En este caso se mostrarán siempre dos decimales.

La otra opción es hacer:

```
return "Ha pasado un {0:.2%} de la hora".format(minuto / 60)
```

Si usas Python >= 3.6 puedes también usar los literales de cadena formateados:

```
return  f"Ha pasado un {minuto / 0.6:.2f}% de la hora."
```

ó:

```
return  f"Ha pasado un {minuto / 60:.2%} de la hora."
```

Ejemplos de ejecución:

> ¿QUÉ PORCENTAJE DE UNA HORA HA TRANSCURRIDO?
>   Introduzca el minuto: 50
>   Ha pasado un 83.33% de la hora.
>
> ¿QUÉ PORCENTAJE DE UNA HORA HA TRANSCURRIDO?
>   Introduzca el minuto: 20
>   Ha pasado un 33.33% de la hora.
>
> ¿QUÉ PORCENTAJE DE UNA HORA HA TRANSCURRIDO?
>   Introduzca el minuto: 64
>   MINUTO INCORRECTO

---

**Edición:**

En cuanto a la explicación de que hace `{0:.2f}`, la estructura general es:

```
{[indice del argumento o palabra clave]:[ancho][.precisión][tipo]}
```

- **`{}`** indica una "diana", será sustituido en la cadena de salida por el argumento correspondiente pasado a `format`, en este caso se sustituye por el resultado de `minuto / 0.6`.

  Es decir, cuando se hace `"Hola {}.".format("Mundo")` lo que hace `format` es coger la cadena `"Hola {}."` y sustituir el `{}` por `"Mundo"`, dando como resultado la cadena `"Hola Mundo."`.
- El primer "0" indica que se use el primer elemento pasado a `format`, en realidad no es necesario en este caso (basta con `:.2f`). Indica el índice del elemento a usar de la tupla pasada a `format`. Si no se especifica se van usando en el orden que tienen en la tupla:

  ```
  >>> "El se llama {} y yo {}.".format("Pedro", "Juán")
  'El se llama Pedro y yo Juán.'
  >>> "El se llama {1} y yo {0}.".format("Pedro", "Juán")
  'El se llama Juán y yo Pedro.'
  >>> "El se llama {0} y yo {1}.".format("Pedro", "Juán")
  'El se llama Pedro y yo Juán.'
  ```
- `f` indica que trate al elemento a formatear como un float, mostrandolo en formato de punto fijo (número fijo de decimales). Podemos ver lo que dice la documentación (Format Specification Mini-Languaje):

  > **f :** Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is 6.
- `.2` indica que la precisión a usar sea imprimiendo solo 2 dígitos después del punto decimal.

Algunos ejemplos:

```
>>> "{:.2f}".format(3.141592)
'3.14'
>>> "{:.4f}".format(3.141592)
'3.1416'
>>> "{:.2f}".format(3)
'3.00'
```

En el caso de `:.2%` es igual, solo que el tipo el argumento es tratado como una frecuencia absoluta y es automáticamente formateada como tanto por cien:

```
>>> "Representa el {:.2%} de los ingresos.".format(0.5) 
'Representa el 50.00% de los ingresos.'
>>> "Representa el {:.2%} de los ingresos.".format(0.2598655) 
'Representa el 25.99% de los ingresos.'
```

Comment: Bueno,como soy nuevo no entiendo muchas cosas. ¿Me podrías decir como funciona el {0:.2f}% del código?