# Error '' 'bool' object is not subscriptable ''

Tags: python, python-3.x

No quiero sonar exigente ni nada asi que solo quiero pedirles un enorme favor, trato de hacer un programa que tenga 20 habitaciones ( son todos esos `s1`,`s2` etc con `true`) me diga si están ocupadas o no , si '`'numero de habitación''==True` está **libre** si es `false` esta **ocupada**, pero al tratar de ejecutar el código me aparece el mensaje, `'bool' object is not subscriptable`, apenas estoy aprendiendo a usar python.

```
s1=True
s2=True
s3=True
s4=True
s5=True
s6=True
s7=True
s8=True

f1=True
f2=True
f3=True
f4=True
f5=True
f6=True
f7=True
f8=True

p1=True
p2=True
p3=True
p4=True
class reservas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Hs={s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8}
        self.Hf={f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8}
        self.Hp={p1,p2,p3,p4}
    def Estado(self):
        print("ingrese el tipo de habitacion")
        print("1) Sencilla")
        print("2) Familiar")
        print("3) Premium")
        self.x=int(input("------>"))
        if self.x==1:
            for i in self.Hs:
                c=0
                if i[c]==True:
                    self.a="Disponible"
                else:
                    self.a="Ocupada"
                print("La habitacion"+str(c),"esta",self.a)
                c=c+1
        elif self.x==2:
            for i in self.Hs:
                c=0
                if i[c]==True:
                    self.a="Disponible"
                else:
                    self.a="Ocupada"
                print("La habitacion"+str(c),"esta",self.a)
                c=c+1
        elif self.x==3:
            for i in self.Hs:
                c=0
                if i[c]==True:
                    self.a="Disponible"
                else:
                    self.a="Ocupada"
                print("La habitacion"+str(c),"esta",self.a)
                c=c+1
        elif self.x>3:
            print("Ingrese un valor correcto")

a=reservas()
a.Estado()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que estas intentado iterar sobre un objeto boleano o intentando acceder a el mediante indexado:

```
>>> s1 = True
>>> s1[0]
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

>>> for e in s1:
...     pass
... 
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

No obstante, tus atributos `Hs`, `Hf` y `Hp` son actualmente conjuntos con un único objeto boleano dentro: `{True}`. Los conjuntos usan tablas hash y sus elementos no pueden estar por tanto repetidos. Cuando haces `self.Hs={s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8}` al ser todas las variables boleanos con valor `True`, es decir tiene todos el mismo hash (1) solo queda una en el conjunto.

Una buena opción, que creo que es lo que en realidad pretendes, es usar diccionarios donde la clave sea una cadena identificando la habitación y el valor el estado de esta.

```
class Reservas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Hs={"s1": True, "s2": True, "s3": True, "s4": True, "s5": True,
                 "s6": True, "s7": True, "s8": True}
        self.Hf={"f1": True, "f2": True, "f3": True, "f4": True, "f5": True,
                 "f6": True, "f7": True, "f8": True}
        self.Hp={"p1": True, "p2": True, "p3": True, "p4": True}

    def estado(self):
        print("ingrese el tipo de habitacion")
        print("1) Sencilla")
        print("2) Familiar")
        print("3) Premium")
        self.x=int(input("------>"))
        if self.x==1:
            for habitacion, estado in self.Hs.items():
                print('{} --> {}.'.format(habitacion,
                                          "Libre" if estado else "Ocupada"))
```

Para cambiar el estado de cualquier habitación simplemente accede usando su clave y cambia su valor:

```
self.Hs["s2"] = False
```

Comment: Disculpa , me podrias decir que hace la funcion ''format'' y el ''.items()''

Comment: @MichaelNavarrete [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) retorna una vista ([View object](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)) que recorre el diccionario y retorna una pareja (clave, valor) en cada iteración. El método `str.format` permite formatear cadenas, mírate mi respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/119535/15089 a otra pregunta a ver si te aclara su funcionamiento. En realidad esto lo he agregado para que vieras como podemos recorrer las habitaciones.

Comment: es decir que dict.items me retornara una pareja, en este caso podria ser "p1" y True ?

Comment: Efectivamente, retorna parejas clave valor en una tupla, si quieres verlo de forma más directa puedes hacer: `d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}`, `for pair in d.items(): print(pair)` , lo cual te muestra dos tuplas con las parejas : `('a', 1)` y `('b', 2)`

Comment: Bueno muchisimas gracias , se que los comentarios no estan para agradecer pero de verdad fue muy util :), por cierto no sabes donde puedo encontrar mas actividades de python o algo asi ?